# In theory, how crackable is this?

Tags: javascript, html, function, security

It basically just uses the value of a five letter password, and ascribes numerals on a variable. What I am asking is in theory, how crackable is this assuming you bring it up to a 20 letter password per say.
[beginning of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWZjb.png)
[end of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xue2m.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please use code blocks instead of putting links to images of your code whenever possible.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code when asking a question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: This could be an interesting algorithm question (I don't know the answer, it's an inventive approach), but the presentation of the question is sorely lacking - see other comments

Comment: Since this is client-side code, I'd just use my browser's dev tools to patch the function to return `true` always.

Comment: how did you pick the numbers? is it possible that multiple inputs lead to the same 'hash'? whats the problem youre solving, versus reusing existing password hashing functions with variable cost and tested strength?

Answer (score 4):

Fundamentally, the encryption scheme you've provided here boils down to this algorithmic question:

> Given a target sum and N lists of K elements each, find a selection of one element from each list such that the sum of the elements is the target sum.

Theoretically, a brute-force solution is exponential time, but I think it has average complexity much lower because we can sort the lists and cut the search short whenever we exceed the limit. This is assuming there are no negative numbers, which there seems not to be.

That said, this can be made equivalent to the [0-1 knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem), which can be solved in O(N*K*sum) time. Even if this is not the optimal approach, it's certainly too fast for this to be considered for any serious cryptographic purposes (as with any home-baked cryptography methods). If this is for anything more than use as a toy cipher, use a [secure cryptographic hash function](https://cryptobook.nakov.com/cryptographic-hash-functions/secure-hash-algorithms) (and don't put authentication on the front-end).

Comment: Also worth noting that regardness of what algorithm is chosen to figure out the sum, it's still going to be *faster* than brute forcing a 5 character password using the alphabet, since it's possible to directly eliminate many combinations and not consider them. While it will still take some time to get the correct password from the sums of numbers, it's will not require generating *all* five letter combinations.

Comment: For what it's worth, my [simple python implementation](https://hastebin.com/awokofugow.lua) of the brute-force solution is able to consistently solve it for length 20 in under a second on my machine.

Comment: Heh, I was thinking of writing a JS attempt but couldn't be bothered. I'd expect execution to not be very long on most machines/browsers. I think it's safe to say that this encryption scheme offers no benefit over literally just checking `password == "12345"` but on the back-end. Or using a proper hashing + salting as a minimum.

Comment: Let's assume we don't know about the implementation. OP's approach still suffers from severely limiting what a user can have as a password. It should be completely normal to allow users *at least* 100 characters for their password. Of course, it's desirable they'd be able to put in *any* password they want, regardless of length and content. This is going to be extremely difficult with OP's approach. Which in turn means users are forced to use *weaker passwords*.

Comment: I thank you for the feedback everybody. I am slowly beginning to learn JavaScript. This was just a small project of mine to prevent you from being able to see the password from directly looking in the code.